# Pandas output difference columns

Tags: pandas, difference

given a df:

```
Id  Name X Y Z
111 abc  1 3 5 
111 abc  0   1
222 ijk    2
222 lmo  1 1
```

Grouping them by Id (since their Ids always match), I would like to output all the column names that has different values:

```
Id  Diff
111 X, Y, Z
222 Name, X, Y
```

Usually I use np.where to spot the difference but I don't think it would help in this case.  Any suggestion would be appreciated.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
In [184]: df.groupby('Id').apply(lambda x: x.columns[x.nunique().ne(1)].tolist())
Out[184]:
Id
111       [X, Y, Z]
222    [Name, X, Y]
dtype: object
```

Also, with column name

```
In [210]: df.groupby('Id').apply(
              lambda x: x.columns[x.nunique().ne(1)].tolist()
            ).reset_index(name='Diff')
Out[210]:
    Id          Diff
0  111     [X, Y, Z]
1  222  [Name, X, Y]
```

Another simpler shorthand could be

```
In [213]: df.groupby('Id').nunique().ne(1).dot(df.columns)
Out[213]:
Id
111       XYZ
222    NameXY
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks!  do you if it's possible to do to create a column name for that.  I tried  df['Diff'] = df.groupby('Id').apply(lambda x: x.columns[x.nunique().ne(1)].tolist()) but didn't work

Answer (score 2):

By using `nunique`

```
s=df.groupby('Id').apply(lambda x : (len(x)<=x.nunique()))

s.mul(s.columns).iloc[:,1:].apply(','.join,1)


Id
111       ,X,Y,Z
222    Name,X,Y,
dtype: object
```

Update

```
s.stack()[s.stack()].reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0)['level_1'].apply(','.join)
Out[959]: 
Id
111       X,Y,Z
222    Name,X,Y
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```

Comment: I got an error for the second line: TypeError: Could not operate Index(['Id', 'Name', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], dtype='object') with block values cannot perform __mul__ with this index type: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>

Comment: @TylerNG  I think you may using different data structure than what you present here, you can try my update method , should be work :-)